# Ubuntu 15.10 not start after update

Tags: 15.10

Ubuntu 15.10 not start after update.
Today i update my ubuntu 15.10 around 11 AM (IST) after update it prompt msg for reboot.
After rebooting ubuntu unable to start.
Then i revert to previous snapshot it works.
But again after software update it unable to start.

Comment: Nice to know at which time you updated your system, but can you provide some error messages too? ;-)

Comment: i updated my system around 11 am (Indian standard time). After that it prompt window "restart now or restart later"
After restarting blank screen only, so cannt say error message.

Comment: Confirm. Same problem, same symptoms

Comment: Same here. Had to boot from 4.2.0.27 as @user44849 notes.

Comment: I have the same problem except that I am working on VMWare !!

Answer (score 5):

Here is the description https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1548587/comments/18

Reboot your PC, hold shift while boot load and select previous kernel. 
Last kernel seems broken

Answer (score 0):

The same happens to me. Today updated the kernel to version 4.2.0.30 and Ubuntu freezes after grub. If I try no start from the upstart option I get this message: "Upstart: broken pipe". And if I start from the recovery and repair packages still freezes.

At this moment, the only thing that I can do is to start from the previous kernel 4.2.0.27.

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: I have the same problem except that I am working on VMWare !!. How can I resolve this